# How does the distance between the center of the north anchor and the north of the node vary by the string length inside the anchor?

Tags: tikz-node

I measured the distance between the center of the north anchor and north of a node and got 7.20068 pt which is 0.1 inches. This is for a especial case as below:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary { calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[simple/.style={rectangle,draw, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10 pt}]



\node[simple] (the node)  {};
\node (the anchor) [red,above] at (the node.north) {$a < b$};


\draw[latex-latex] let \p1 = ($(the anchor.center)-(the node.north)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (the 
node.north) --  node[above] {\n1} (the anchor.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The main question is: assuming the fontsize is constant let us say 10 pt, how the length of the string inside anchor affects this distance? If instead of $a > b$ we make a longer string such as $aaaaaaaaaaaaa$ the distance described above changes. The question is how it varies.

Comment: Hi Aria, I answered your question, but without context what you want to achieve, it is hard to help. I therefore had to stick to the questions, as they were worded.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not disclosing for what purpose you need to know the distance between node center and north anchor, it is really hard to help here, therefore I answer your questions straight:

*Is this true in general?*

No it is not, because the size of a node is dependent on its content, therefore imagine your node has another font size, like `\node (the anchor) [red,above] at (the node.north) {\LARGE $a < b$};`, then the distance is different, too:

[image]

*If not, what is the default distance?*

Following the logic of the size dependency from the content, there cannot be a default distance.